# IMDB scrapy get movie date in meta content

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Hi I want to extract the content in meta, which is the date of the movie. If I use

```
response.xpath("//*[@title='See more release dates']/meta").extract()
```

it only get me to here:

```
[u'<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="1904-06-29">']
```

How can I get the date in the content? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `content` attribute value via `@content`:

```
response.xpath("//*[@title='See more release dates']/meta/@content").extract_first()
```

Note that I'm using `extract_first()` instead of `extract()` to get the string value and not a list.